# how to eliminate the horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a website and one of my biggest problem right now is making it fit on all screens and mobile friendly. One of my biggest problems with that is the horizontal scrollbar! I appreciate anything that can be offered.

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5e/Metro-M.svg/2000px-Metro-M.svg.png">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="about.css">
<title>morgan</title>
<style>
html {
  background: URL("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-lYQ3vQHE3Mo/VrVKGwg8pqI/AAAAAAAADMQ/QKjs5ALViKo/w530-d-h253-p-rw/desk%2Bbackground.png") white no-repeat center top;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
overflow-x: none; 
}
h2 {
Font-family: Arial;
top: 650px;
left: 500px;
position: absolute;
color: #525252;
font-size: 2vw;
letter-spacing: 1px;

}
h3 {
Font-family: Arial;
top: 900px;
left: 500px;
position: absolute;
color: #525252;
font-size: 2vw;
letter-spacing: 1px;

}
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 21%;
  left: 36%;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 4.6vw;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  top: 720px;
  left: 310px;
  height: 25px;
  font-family: Gill Sans, sans-serif;
color:#696969;
font-size: 17px;
 text-align: center;
line-height: 150%;
}

a {
color: white;
text-decoration:none;
}

ul li {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 40px;
  top: 43%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 250px;
  margin-left: 115px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  word-spacing: normal;
  background-color: rgba(5, 4, 2, 0.1);
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 90%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
}
ul li:link,
ul li:visited {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 250px;
  margin-left: 115px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  word-spacing: normal;
  background-color: rgba(5, 4, 2, 0.1);
  border: 2px solid white;
  font-size: 90%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
li {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
ul li:hover,
ul li:active {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a:hover, ul li a:active {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}  

ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
margin-right: 10%;
}  

.wrapper {
  padding-top: 0%;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {

  .wrapper {
    padding-top: 40%;
  }

ul li{
   margin-left: 2px;
   margin-top: 5px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   width: 100px;
   height:35px;
   top: 480%;
  }
ul{
margin-top: 165px;
margin-left: 20px;
}
  h1{
    position:absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 150px;
    font-size: 19px;
 }
h2 {

    font-size: 20px;
    width: 200px; 
    left: 100px;
    top: 200px;
}

p {
    left: 30px;
    top: 390px;
}
hr {
margin-right: 85px;
margin-left: 85px;
margin-top: 375px;
}

}

hr {
margin-right: 150px;
margin-left: 150px;
margin-top: 570px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center><h1>WHO I AM</h1></center>

<div class="wrapper">
<ul>
<li><a href="www.youtube.com" class="life" ><strong>MY LIFE</strong></a></li>
<li><a href="www.youtube.com" class="prot"><strong>PORTFOLIO</strong></a></li>
<li><a href="www.youtube.com" class="resume"><strong>RESUME</strong></a></li>
<li><a href="about.html" class="me"><strong>ABOUT ME</strong></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<h2>Some Fun Facts</h2>
<p>
I made this website from scratch when I was 14, I have a twin brother whose <br> 
name is Pierson McNeal White, I have a older brother and sister who are also <br>
twins, I used to have 2 pet rats named Hermes and Cleo after the greek gods, <br>
and I watch the super bowl for the ads.
</p> 
<hr>
<h3>Me In A Nutshell</h3> 
</body>
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question? You are kind of asking 2 different questions. To remove the horizontal scroll bar is pretty easy, you could use Michael's solution. But in your "question" you mention you want it to fit on all devices which is a lot different then just removing a scrollbar.

Comment: oh well both answers would be nice...

Comment: You should ask one question for one problem! :-)

Comment: ok just the scroll bar!

Comment: then you have my answer to solve it. Can you please form another question  for the alignment problem? A fiddle would be helpful - and the desired output, too!

Comment: fiddle? ok thank you

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: ooh ok thank you i will learn that

Comment: you're getting the scroll bar because you're setting the width of elements in px, and adding, in some cases, large margins to them. once the browser window is smaller than your widths, it's going to give you scroll bars. i'd suggest using percentages for your widths, and calculating them based on the target / context = result formula.

Comment: ok thank you i will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messed around with your code, didnt spend all day though. So there is still room for improvement, but fish around in here and pick what you like or build off of it.

```css
body {
 background-color: #e3e3e3;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: Arial;
}
.header {
 background: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-lYQ3vQHE3Mo/VrVKGwg8pqI/AAAAAAAADMQ/QKjs5ALViKo/w530-d-h253-p-rw/desk%2Bbackground.png) no-repeat left fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 text-align: center;
 height: 400px;
 }
 
.mobilelinks {display: none;}

.wrapper {
 margin: 50px;
}

#footer {
 text-align: center;
}

#footer a {
 color: #666;
 margin-left: 8px;
}

#footer a:hover {
 color: #222;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

h1 {
 color: white;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 72px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}
h2 {
 color: #525252;
 font-size: 36px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 text-align: center;

}
p {
 font-family: Gill Sans, sans-serif;
 color:#696969;
 font-size: 17px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 150%;
}
a {
 color: white;
 text-decoration:none;
}

ul li {
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 40px;
 display: inline-block;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 background-color: rgba(5, 4, 2, 0.1);
 border: 2px solid white;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 90%;
 width: 150px;
 height: 40px;
}

ul li:hover {
 background-color: white;
}

ul li:hover > a {
 color: #000;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
 .header {height: 300px;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 h1 {
  font-size: 52px;
 }
 .links {display: none;}
 .mobilelinks {display: inline-block;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
 .header {height: 200px;}
 .mobile-terms { display: none;}
 h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
 }
 h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
 }
}
```

```html
<head>
<title>Morgan the Great</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5e/Metro-M.svg/2000px-Metro-M.svg.png">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  </head>
<body>
 <div class="header">
  <h1>Morgan White</h1>
   <ul class="links">
    <li><a href="www.youtube.com"><strong>MY LIFE</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="www.youtube.com"><strong>PORTFOLIO</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="www.youtube.com"><strong>RESUME</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html"><strong>ABOUT ME</strong></a></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="mobilelinks">
    <li><a href="www.youtube.com"><strong>BUTTON</strong></a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="mainwrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <h2>Some Fun Facts</h2>
    <p>
    I made this website from scratch when I was 14, <br>
    I have a twin brother whose name is Pierson McNeal White, <br>
    I have a older brother and sister who are also twins, <br>
    I used to have 2 pet rats named Hermes and Cleo after the greek gods, <br>
    and I watch the super bowl for the ads.
    </p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <h2>Me In A Nutshell</h2>
    <p>
    Other Crap Here.
    </p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="footer">
            Copyright &copy;&nbsp;<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script>&nbsp;Morgan.
          <div>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
            <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
            <a href="#">Terms<span class="mobile-terms"> of Service</span></a>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Works on mobile devices.

Comment: could you explain to me what you did?

Comment: how did you get the header where it is and buttons?

Comment: I just changed the way the css is. I gave the top elements in header align text center so that it centered with the div it-self. i added `margin: 0 auto;` into the body element so that everything is centered within the page. I also cleaned up repeated css. I dropped most of your absolute positions because its hard to make absolute responsive, plus most weren't necessary

Comment: oh ok thank you it takes a special person to do something that takes so long (well maybe not for you) for someone you don't even know! (that or you just really like to code) for any reason, thank you.

Comment: Thanks man, its a little of both. when i was learning I had a couple of people point me in the right direction so its only fair to return the favor. when I have spare time i help as much as i can. good luck coding!

Comment: thank you.  My website should be up soon I am using filezilla so if you ever want to see my progress here's the link: www.morganawhite.com

Answer (score 2):

Simply use

```
overflow-x: none;
```

for the horizontal scrollbar issue.

```
html {
  background: URL("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-lYQ3vQHE3Mo/VrVKGwg8pqI/AAAAAAAADMQ/QKjs5ALViKo/w530-d-h253-p-rw/desk%2Bbackground.png") #363634 no-repeat center top;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-x: none;  
}
```